# Recursive header expansion failed at react-native-google-signin

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, node-modules, google-signin

I am working on an already build react native project (working on peer's computer). When I try to run in my computer (ios) it is fixated at following error:

Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at /node_modules/react-native-google-signin/ios/../../../ios/Pods/React/node_modules/module_deps/node_modules/minimist/example.

1. https://textuploader.com/d7sdh -- Package.json file (1 year expire)
2. https://textuploader.com/d7sdx -- Pod file (1 year expire)

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYb9f.png)

I have tried :

1. delete & reinstall node modules.
2. delete & install pods.
3. delete derived data.
4. react-native link.

   btw https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/issues/338 does not work

Comment: This is a reported issue on official google sigin plugin for react native. Have a look here -  https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/pull/333

Comment: After going through the conversations happen on Pull request #393 https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/pull/393. Looks like this issue is resolved. Can you please try upgrading the lib. to the latest version? Or better follow the official guide once again.

Comment: Hello, Thank you. Doing https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/pull/333/commits/1c99bcf05c77f54e2582fe25fdae93bfcef23c7f changes worked for me.